In Power BI, how can I create 7 day buckets that are calculated dynamically from the selected date in a date filter?
I am working on a Power BI dashboard where I need to create a bar chart that shows 8 bars for the last 8 weeks. The first bar from the right, shows the last 7 days and every next bar the 7 days before that. This should be dynamically changing based on the selected date.
So when I select a date in the past, the last 7 days (will still be called last 7 days) and will be the 7 days before the selected date, starting on selected date -1. This means the buckets should have dynamically build up weeks. Meaning the 7 days does not correspond with week numbers (the dates in buckets keep shifting)
In my chart I want to visualize the amount of members that joined per 7 day bucket. This is based on my measure that calculates the distinct contractkeys where startdate = dates in buckets.
I have attempted the following but since I work with week index it's always calculated from the actual current date instead of the selected date:
Y axis:

# Agg CY Joiners = 
VAR CurrentDate = MIN('date'[Date])
VAR StartDate = CurrentDate - 6 -- Adjust to get the start of the 7-day period
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
       [# Base Joiners], 
        Contracts_v1[StartDate] >= StartDate &&
        Contracts_v1[Startdate] <= CurrentDate 
    )

(# Base Joiners is a measure to determine the Joiners that are in scope based on true/false parameters)
X-axis (column in date table)
    "Rolling Week Index",  CEILING(DATEDIFF(today(),[Date], DAY)/ 7,1)

Anyone has experience with this or knows a solution to achieve what I need?
Thank you in advance!

here is a workaround for you.

create a date table and use that to select date.
date= CALENDAR(min('Table'[date]),max('Table'[date]))

create a measure, add that measure to visual filter and set value is 1.
 MEASURE =
 IF (
     MAX ( 'Table'[date] ) <= MAX ( 'date'[Date] )
         && MAX ( 'Table'[date] )
             >= MAX ( 'date'[Date] ) - 6,
     1
 )




